# Eclipse how can I indent C++ preprocessor macros

Tags: c++, eclipse

I can't find a setting in eclipse so that I can have it automatically indent my preprocessor macros the same way it indents code.  For example eclipse tries to format code like this.

```
int main()
{
#ifdef SOMETHING
     cout << "Something Defined" << endl;
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

Whereas I want it to look like...

```
int main()
{
    #ifdef SOMETHING
     cout << "Something Defined" << endl;
    #endif
    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas to make eclipse do it how I want?

Answer (score 2):

Pre-ANSI C preprocessor did not allow for space between the start of a line and the "#" character; the leading "#" had to always be placed in the first column.

Pre-ANSI C compilers are non-existent these days. Use which ever style (space before "#" or space between "#" and the identifier) you prefer.

But I suggest you do this:
[image]

Just use Find/Replace dialog and the push "Replace all"

Comment: Well I know that I can just reindent everything but it is kind of annoying since I have to do this after every line since when I type the # the editor automatically removes my indentation.

Comment: +1 for having looked up the standard. This annoys the f*** out of me too, given the insane complexity of Eclipse & its settings you'd think they could stand to let us indent things if we really want to...

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse indentation is correct. Preprocessor directives should be on the leftmost column, regardless of the indentation of the surrounding code.

Comment: Any objective reason? "It stands out more, and I find it should stand out."?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no option for macro indentation. But I see clangformat seems to have option for macro indentation so you can customize your own clang format (http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) and configure eclipse to use clangformat instead of the default.

Comment: There's even a plugin that integrates clang-format as an alternative code formatter for Eclipse: [CppStyle](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/cppstyle), [CppStyle's Github repo](https://github.com/wangzw/CppStyle)

Answer (score 1):

To indent the preprocessor you might need to use [Neatbens](https://netbeans.org/) instead. It's formatter disregard the preANSIc.

Comment: I knew that.  I'm not going to just switch to netbeans for this minor reason though.

Comment: You are right, but i did that to skip time at least to submit before the deadline, i believe there's a way to "convince" eclipse to read the configuration of indenting the macros though.

Answer (score 0):

Like others already pointed out compiler directives `#` have to start in the first column to be standard conform. Nevertheless it is allowed to put spaces behind them. So my preferred solution looks as follows and then it should no longer be an eclipse issue.

```
int main()
{
#  ifdef SOMETHING
     cout << "Something Defined" << endl;
#  endif
}
```